# Erro ao compilar programa

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com esses erros, sendo que está funcionando!

Eu adicionei a referencia, está a pasta BLL certa pelo caminho. Já tentei e pesquisei por tudo mas não entendo o que eu tenho que fazer. Já recriei o projeto 3 vezes e não consigo tirar esse erro para compilar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E agora esta também dando esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que poderia fazer para resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

o primeiro erro refere-se a versão do framework utilizada, está avisando que o npgsql requer o .net 4.5.1 e você está utilizando o 4.5. 
em sua solução, vá em propriedades e altere o framework utilizado.

o segundo erro, refere-se que você não pode iniciar o programa por uma DLL, 
você deve definir uma aplicação como projeto inicial. Clique com o botão direito em GUI, em seguida em 'Set as startup project'

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda. Não tinha reparado isso, falta de atenção da minha parte. Mas mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não consigo perceber bem a sua questão, a imagem que publicaste com o erro, não esta visível da para mandares uma outra imagem?

Mas antes testa isso: vai ate a  "soluntion explore" com o cursor em cima do nome do projecto clica no sub-menu do rato(mose) vai até propriedade e selecciona a opção" Set as sartup Project " se não resultar faz o seguinte, onde esta Debung substitui com o Releasse.